# setUpdatePeriod() in gmapping?

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm tracing the code of gmapping and try to find out the parameter "temporalUpdate" usage in:
https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/gmapping

In slam_gmapping.cpp(https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/hydro-devel/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp), it looks like the parameter is used in line#508

```
line#508:  gsp_->setUpdatePeriod(temporalUpdate_);
```

but I can not find the setUpdatePeriod() method in gridslamprocessor.cpp or gridslamprocessor.h.

https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/gmapping/trunk/gridfastslam/gridslamprocessor.cpp

Anybody find it??

ps. I'm using ROS distribution "indigo".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222474/setupdateperiod()-in-gmapping?/) by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2015-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found it!!  It's in
http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/openslam_gmapping/html/gridslamprocessor_8cpp_source.html

Kevin Kuei

---

Originally posted by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) with karma: 159 on 2015-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0